# How to Modify Keyboard Drivers

Tags: linux, drivers, keyboard

I have a keyboard that has a few buttons that my OS does not recognize when pressed. As I understand it, this has something to do with the drivers not fully communicating with the keyboard (?). I have seen many people write custom drivers for certain keyboards but there hasn't been one developed for my keyboard (that I've found. It's a GSkill km780r).

I don't know assembly code or machine code or anything of that nature and so I think it would take too long for me to learn that and write my own drivers. My question would be what is the feasibility of just modifying the current drivers I have to recognize the extra buttons?

I used xev and can confirm pressing the extra keys do not register

Comment: It is very unlikely the drivers are the problem.

Comment: What could be the issue then?

Answer (score 2):

This issue has nothing to do with drivers.  The keyboard driver is installed and your keyboard is working.  However, your issue is that Linux doesnt know what to do with the custom scan codes generated by the keyboard.  Scan codes are the data given by the keyboard to the computer, which then determines what key was pressed.

Here is [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143757/linux-kernel-dropping-custom-keyboard-scan-codes) on another SE site that explains how to fix the issue.

Comment: I attempted to use dmesg like they said to do in the link, but dmesg isn't outputting the response expected "unknown key pressed". I don't understand why it isn't a driver, when I search the internet for this a bunch of other gaming keyboards come up with linux drivers being created for them, ie openrazer

Comment: @GrahamChapman the driver is working fine.  the driver has nothing to do with the unknown scan codes.